# Linear regression with group-dependent intercept and variance

Tags: multiple-regression, linear-model, fixed-effects-model

This is my first question on CrossValidated and I'm not a professional statistician (although I am trained in theoretical probability) so please be indulgent.

I have data of the form $(X_i, Y_i, K_i)_{1 \leq i \leq n}$  where $X_i,Y_i$ are 1-dimensional continuous variables and $K_i$ is categorical (ordinal in fact), representing the group in which the $i$-th observation belongs. I want to fit a linear regression model in order to explain the dependent variable $Y_i$ by a multiple of $\alpha X_i$, plus an intercept that depends on the group, so 
$$ Y_i = \alpha X_i + \beta(K_i) + \varepsilon_i$$
I have been able to estimate $\alpha$ and the $\beta(k)$s by introducing dummy regressors $X^k_i = 1_{K_i=k}$, and running a simple OLS estimator on the formula `Y ~ X + Z1 + ... + Z8 - 1`.

But I have reasons to think that the residual variance is different from one group to another : $\mathrm{Var}(\varepsilon_i|X) = \sigma^2(K_i)$ and obviously unknown. I think this will have a material effect on the estimates but I don't know how to implement this (say in R). My googling has led me to the package "RFGLS" but I'm not sure how to apply it to my situation since I'm not familiar with the whole "fixed effects" / "random effects" terminology.

I would very much appreciate if anyone could provide me with tips as to how to estimate this model, or with a formulation of my problem in the canonical statistical language.

Thanks.

PS : If it helps, the function $k \mapsto \beta(k)$ is expected to be decreasing, and this is true of the OLS estimates $\hat{\beta}_k$. I expect it to be also true for the variance function $k \mapsto \sigma^2(k)$.

PS2 : Actually my ultimate hope is to prove that $\alpha$ is "reasonably" close to zero, for instance by not being able to reject $H_0 : \alpha=0$ at the $5\%$ level (I'm aware using hypothesis testing to "prove" the null is not exactly good practice).

Edit : Sorry I didn't make this clear in the first place : my working hypothesis is that the $\varepsilon_i$s are centered and mutually independent given $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the mixed effects regression, such as PROC MIXED in SAS. Your equation would be something like this: $Y_ik=X_{ik}\beta_{1k}+\beta_{0k}$,

then $\beta_{0k}=\gamma_{0k}+\varepsilon_{0k}$

and $\beta_{1k}=\gamma_{1k}$

Something along this line, make sure to familiarize yourself with [Longitudinal Data Analysis](http://faculty.washington.edu/heagerty/Courses/VA-longitudinal/private/LDAchapter.pdf), the common key word in this domain is "mixed effects" regression

you can set the correlation structure on $\varepsilon_{0k}$ errors, e.g. diagonal.

Comment: I want to believe his correlation matrix is diagonal . GLMM might not be a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks. You are both right ; in fact there may be some correlations between the groups and a longitudinal model might be more appropriate, but first I want to look at the case of independent errors. I should have made it clearer in my post.

Comment: @PLV, i'm afraid you need the fixed or random effect around the error variance between groups, if you observe different dispersions between groups.

Answer (score 1):

[image]I made a little plot for you. If the image is exactly what you want, then the model of form $Y=\beta_0+\beta_1K+\beta_2X+\epsilon$ will solve the problem. We have the same gradient for all groups but different intercepts. So that $Y|K=\beta_0+\beta_1k+\beta_2X+\epsilon$ guaranteeing for the different intercepts

Comment: Thank you Chamberlain. My data indeed looks like this, except that 1) the X ranges are shifted from one group to another 2) the dispersion around the line (the sigmas) are different from one group to another.

Comment: but how would this model show different error variances for groups?

Comment: Sorry if I'm being unclear ; I assume that $Y_i = aX_i + \beta(K_i) + \sigma(K_i) u_i$, where $u_i$ is white noise, and I want to estimate $a$ and the $\beta(k)$s. The $\sigma(k)$s can be considered as "nuisance parameters" is this is the right expression.